# My recordset returns only one record even though there are more one record in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, recordset

I am creating a form that loads all the information from the `Activity_Table` into the form. So basically when the user chooses the name of the Company from the `Company_Name` drop down,  and selects the site from the `Site_Name` combo box, it is supposed to return the values from that site and put them into the form.

Basically one site can appear more than once in the `Activity_Table`. Yet, whenever the user selects the name of the site, it only returns one record. To make sure of this, I used the `.Recordcount` method to check how many records that will be retrieved.

So when you check the Activity table, the Site "Accra Mall - 630kva Gen 2 " appears 4 times, yet when you check the recordcount, it only says it appears Once. So because of this, I cannot move either forward or backwards to either the next or previous record.

To make sure that there was nothing wrong with my sql, I run the query in the Query Design and it produced all 4 records of "Accra Mall - 630kva Gen 2".
So there is nothing wrong with the sql statement. Can anyone help me out please?

[This is when I choose the name of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySo5H.png)

[We can see that it returns only One record here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSiQa.png)

[Yet this is the amount of records it's supposed to produce(This was when I tried the sql code in the query design tab. It returns 4 records, Not 1). So the recordcount is supposed to be 4. Not One.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM2E0.png)

[this is when I tried the sql to in the previous picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cAqL.png)

Comment: Check properties of the form, that you haven't set a Filter on the form.

Comment: how are you grabbing the record count? You might want to execute a move last before you display that msg box with the count.

Answer (score 0):

If I replicated your problem correctly then the answer is to set Data-Entry to no.  Check your form properties.  Under the data tab there is a data-entry property. set data-entry to no.  From microsoft at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dataentry-property-f4236759-27f6-4fcd-abb0-4aa4acd8fe87 we get an explanation:
You can use the DataEntry property to specify whether a bound form opens to allow data entry only. The Data Entry property doesn't determine whether records can be added; it only determines whether existing records are displayed. Read/write Boolean.

Comment: WOW! Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem with only returning one record from a table of 350.

My form was set to 'Single Form' when it should have been 'Continuous Form'.

A dumb mistake by me apparently.